# Is the ridge of a sum of "ridged" functions on the intersection of the ridges of those functions?

Tags: calculus, optimization

Suppose you have two bivariate  continuous, bounded functions $f_1(x,y)$ and $f_2(x,y)$.
 Furthermore, for both, there is a continuous path of the form

$$y=g_1(x),y=g_2(x)$$

on which the functions are equal to $f_1^*$ and $f_2^*$, their respective  global maximae, that is:

$$f_1(x,g_1(x))=f_1^*\;\forall (x,y):y=g_1(x)$$

and

$$f_2(x,g_2(x))=f_2^*\;\forall (x,y):y=g_2(x)$$

(I don't know if such functions have a distinctive name).

Moreover, I also know that we have at least one point $x_0$ such that:

$$x_0:g_1(x_0)=g_2(x_0).$$

Now, I am dealing with a function of the form:

$$h(x,y)=f_1(x,y)+f_2(x,y)$$

Is it reasonable to assert that under the conditions above $h^*$ (the global maximum of $h$) satisfies $h^*=h(x_0,g_1(x_0))$?

Comment: Sure, if $h=f+g$ then $h^*\le f^*+g^*$. But at $(x_0,g_1(x_0))$ you have $h=f^*+g^*$, so it must be equal to $h^*$.

Comment: Thanks! This is fantastic;) One thing: how can one justify the inequality "if $g=f+g$ then $h^∗\leq f^*+g^*$"?

Comment: $h^*=\max h=\max(f+g)\le\max(f^*+g^*)=f^*+g^*$.